# List updation in multi-threaded scenario in java

Tags: java, multithreading, list, synchronization

I have a scenario in which I need to do some processing on a very large List (say 9000+) entries and then added the processed entries to a new list. So to do this I am taking multi-threaded approach.

Among the following two ways, which one would be more efficient:

1. I should give separate list objects to each thread and then add the results from all the threads into one ultimate list.
2. I should use a synchronized list and give allow all the threads to simultaneously add to this list.

Comment: this needs way more information to give a real answer to

Answer (score 2):

Thread work best when they can work independently. I would favour given each thread its own work and collecting the results when they have finished.

In this example each thread work independently.

```
ExecutorService service = 
List<Work> workList = 
int blockSize = (workList.size() + threads -1)/threads;
List<Future<List<Results>>> futureResults = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<threads;i++) {
    int start = i * blockSize;
    int end = Math.min(workList.size(), (i + 1) * blockSize);
    final List<Work> list2 = worksList.subList(start, end);
    futureResults.add(service.submit(new Callable<List<Results>>() {
        public List<Results> call() {
             return process(list2);
        }
     });
 }
 List<Results> results = new ArrayList<>();
 for(Future<List<Results>> future:futureResults) 
     results.addAll(future.get());
```

Comment: By implementing the Executor Service and CompletionExecutorService, I can see the performance improvement of around 40%. CompletionExecutorService is really good as far as the performance gain is concerned in managing callable threads.

Comment: The CompletionExecutorService is useful, but I don't see how it will affect performance.

Comment: Here when you are doing sequential "future.get()", then it might happen that a task which comes early in the sequence is not yet completed and you are spending time waiting for it to complete. So CompletionExectutorService actually picks the last completed task from the pool, which is better than going sequentially.

Comment: If you can process the results out of order, you can add this work to the tasks themselves and do the processing concurrently.  You would only do things in the calling thread which can only be done when all the results have finished. (Or to process the result in a particular order) In this situation, it doesn't matter when individual tasks finished only the when all the tasks finish, which will be the same no matter how you get the data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why do you think threading is a solution, you don't really list a problem that concurrency solves?

In the grand scheme of things 9000 entries isn't a lot of things to process. If you had said, 9 million entries and each entry takes 10 seconds to process, that might be a different story.

Unless processing each thing takes a very long time ( relatively ) and is **not** CPU bound ( like waiting on a remote machine to do something ), I would say multi-threading in this situation isn't going to give you anything but un-needed complexity.

Even with long processing times, threading implies shared data, from the very sparse vague information you have provided a simple asynchronous approach would probably work better with a `Queue` from `java.util.concurrency`.